# How to put database records into an iText pdf table report in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, itext, pdfptable

So I want to connect my records into an iText **table** report. I managed to just list all my records inside the PDF but not putting them inside a table.

```
if (option.equals("Download all records.")) {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet records = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER_INFO");

    try {
        while (records.next()) {
            if (un.equals(records.getString("username")))
                document.add(new Paragraph("*" + records.getString("username") + ", " + records.getString("role")));
            else
                document.add(new Paragraph(records.getString("username") + ", " + records.getString("role")));
        }

    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreatePdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

} else {
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USER_INFO WHERE USERNAME =?");
    stmt.setString(1, un);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        document.add(new Paragraph(rs.getString("username") + ", " + rs.getString("role")));
    }
}

document.add(new Paragraph(footer));
document.close();

}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CreatePdf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I want the format of my table to look like this

| username | role |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | pass1 |
| so on... | so on... |

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the content of the records to the `document` immediately, create a `Table` (iText 7) or `PdfPTable` (iText 5) first, and add the content of the records as cells to the table. When all the records are added, add the table to the document.

## iText 7

At the start of your code, create a table:

```java
Table table = new Table(2);
```

Any (visual) properties of the table, such as alignment, width and borders, can be configured on the `Table` instance.

Instead of adding `Paragraph`s to the `document`, add `Cell`s to the `table`:

```java
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(records.getString("username"))));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(records.getString("role"))));
```

Finally, add the table to the document:

```java
document.add(table);
document.add(new Paragraph(footer));
```

## iText 5

For iText 5, it's very similar:

```java
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
```

```java
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(new Paragraph(records.getString("username")));
table.addCell(cell);
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
cell2.addElement(new Paragraph(records.getString("role")));
table.addCell(cell2);
```

```java
document.add(table);
document.add(new Paragraph(footer));
```